# List traverse back in java

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I traverse back in array list in java...

Even I have the code to traverse forward direction ...

but I couldn't consider that to traverse backward..

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("Raj");
        al.add("Sameer");
        al.add("Nitu");
        al.add("Biren");
        al.add("Vishal");
        Iterator<String> it = al.iterator();
        System.out.println("Forward direction:-");
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java array list provide us the both feature to go forward or go backward....

Here if we use the ListIterator instead of Iterator than it works..

Here is the code try it.....

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("Raj");
        al.add("Sameer");
        al.add("Nitu");
        al.add("Biren");
        al.add("Vishal");
        ListIterator<String> it = al.listIterator();
        System.out.println("Forward direction:-");
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println("\nBackward direction:-");
        while(it.hasPrevious())
        {
            System.out.println(it.previous());
        }
```

Comment: its my pleasure

Comment: ofcourse  but actually i don't know about list iterator i only know about the iterator..

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `ListIterator` :

```
System.out.println("Backward direction:-");
ListIterator<String> it = al.listIterator(al.size()); // this initializes the iterator to 
                                                      // point to the end of the list
while(it.hasPrevious())
{
    System.out.println(it.previous());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working on an implementation of `List` you can get a `ListIterator` by calling `al.listIterator( al.size() )`. That iterator provides methods like `previous()` to iterate backwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.reverse(arr);` example:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
System.err.println("Before");
arr.add(10);
arr.add(20);
arr.add(30);
for(Object c: arr){
    System.out.println(c);
}
Collections.reverse(arr);
System.out.println("after");
for(Object c: arr){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: @V.Deep I add sample above.If this not help you please let me know